# How to check gaps in date ranges - sql

Tags: sql

I have a table of months, and it has two columns of dates : start date, and end date. And I need your help to **check** the missing months in date ranges using a simple sql query.

The example below illustrates sample of data:

```
08/12/2018 - 06/01/2019
07/01/2019 - 05/02/2019
08/03/2019 - 05/04/2019
06/04/2019 - 05/05/2019
```

Expected result:

Missing months

```
06/02/2019 - 07/03/2019
06/05/2019 - 03/06/2019
```

Note that l’m using Hijri calendar not Gregorian calendar, so the first month in my example which is 08/12/2018 G refers to this date 01/04/1440 H in Hijri calendar , and its end date 06/01/2019 refers to 30/04/1440 H and so on.. Note that I used this date format DD/MM/YYYY and Oracle sql DB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just can't figure out what the result set has to do with the input data.  Where does 07/03/2019 come from?  Why is your question about *months* if the results are *days*?  Why are you not using YYYY-MM-DD for the dates (your dates are ambiguous)?  What database are you using?

Comment: I want to note that l’m using Hijri calendar not Gregorian calendar, so the first month in my example which is 08/12/2018 G refers to this date 01/04/1440 H in Hijri calendar , and its end date 06/01/2019 refers to 30/04/1440 H and so on.. Note that I used this date format DD/MM/YYYY and Oracle sql DB.

Comment: . . Regardless of the calendar you are using, you should still write the dates as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result does not seem to match your sample data and explanation, but I understand that you want to exhibit the boundaries of intervals that are not adjacent. You could do this with `lag()`:

```
select 
    end_date + interval 1 day start_gap,
    lead_start_date - interval 1 day end_gap
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lead(start_date) over(order by start_date) lead_start_date
    from mytable t
) t
where lead_start_date > end_date + interval 1 day
```

This uses standard date arithmetic; the exact syntax may vary depending on your RDBMS.